# css div taking up whole screen

Tags: html, css

[I have the following fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1bzpaLfd/) that when you run it shows a red border that indicates my div that is in question.  **Really I want my div to be under the 2 divs above it that are on the right and left sides.**

The div in question is this:

```
    <div id="Tabs" role="tabpanel" style=" position:relative; width:100%; border:1px solid red;">
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="active"><a href="#sqlOutput" aria-controls="sqlOutput" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">"U or R" Table Scripts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#sqlCRUD" aria-controls="sqlCRUD" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">"U or R" Table CRUD</a></li>
            <li><a href="#sqlETable" aria-controls="sqlETable" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">"E" Table Scripts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#xTableInserts" aria-controls="xtablecrud" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">"X" Table Scripts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#JSONDATA" aria-controls="JSONDATA" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">JSON DATA</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content" style="padding-top: 20px; overflow:auto;">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="sqlOutput" ng-bind-html="sqlOutput  | unsafe" style="height:200px; overflow:auto;"></div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="sqlCRUD" ng-bind-html="sqlCRUD  | unsafe" style="height:200px; overflow:auto;"></div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="sqlETable" ng-bind-html="sqlETable  | unsafe" style="height:200px; overflow:auto;"></div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="xTableInserts" ng-bind-html="xTableInserts  | unsafe" style="height:200px; overflow:auto;"></div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="JSONDATA" ng-bind-html="JSONDATA  | unsafe" style="height:200px; overflow:auto;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please advise on what I need to change?  You may notice in my fiddle that there are duplicate body instructions.  I have the dashboard.css (bootstrap theme) and the bootstrap.css combined there.

Comment: Can you be more specific what div? Also why is there so much CSS in the fiddle? It would be better if you linked to bootstrap CSS externally, and only have **your** added CSS in the fiddle.

Comment: in the fiddle is the one with the red border.  Which is the div in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clear the floated elements. In this case you can use a `<div class="clearfix"></div>` between the two columns and your red div. I suggest using the [bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) though.

https://jsfiddle.net/1bzpaLfd/1/

Comment: Thanks.  I'll take a look at the bootstrap grid